# Moving text and tables between pages after exporting in docx

Tags: jasper-reports, docx, export-to-word

I'd like to be able to edit my word document like said in the title. This is what my document look like after exporting to docx:

[image]

**Structure**: the table is generated with seven cells in a detail band. Every page have a footer and header of fixed length.

**Problem**: if i delete something on the first page, my text on the second page doesn't go up to the first. I managed to get text and tables moving in the same page but can't figure out how to do this with different pages. Jasper export to .docx using tables, you can see the gridlines in the picture. Table structure prevent the elements to float between pages. If i delete manually the "header" and "footer" tables from the document, my second page cells go up to the first. But it's a pain to edit manually every page of a 20 pages document everytime.

**Desired solution**: I want the text or tables to go up if i'm simply deleting something on the previous page.

Tried every combination of floating elements, subreport, stretc and so on. Nothing worked.

I know Jasper is not intended for massive editing after exporting but this is what i need now.